# Email client like functionality using IMAP and JavaMail API

Tags: gmail, jakarta-mail, imap

How do I implement an email client like functionality using IMAP and JavaMail API?

I have to download and sync all emails from all the folders of GMAIL account to my database.

Comment: How can I do an incremental sync after the first time full download?

Comment: Open the "all mail" mailbox, or all of them, download all the messages and keep track of the modseq of each messages. To sync, look for messages with modseqs higher than you saw last time. Next time, please ask a less broad question.

Comment: Assuming the messages in the database are never modified locally, this is relatively easy.  The more general case is described in the RFCs referenced in [this JavaMail FAQ entry about disconnected support](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#disco).

Comment: Thanks for reply. How can I handle deleted mails from inbox or movement from one folder to another.